# Making a (unity) moment script that allows my character to have dynamic jump, coyote time, jump buffering, and dash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and am trying to take two scripts that I have written based on youtube tutorials and make a script that allows my character to have dynamic jump, coyote time, jump buffering, and dash. Everything is working except for the dash now. When I play, all of the features work, including the anti-gravity during the dash, but my character does not speed up; it remains at the same speed as when walking. I think the two IEnumerator may be conflicting, but I am unsure of how to resolve it. So far, everything I have tried has not worked. I appreciate the help! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiE8t.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementBendux : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    public float speed = 8f;
    public float jumpingPower = 16f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    private bool isJumping;

    private float coyoteTime = 0.2f;
    private float coyoteTimeCounter;

    private float jumpBufferTime = 0.2f;
    private float jumpBufferCounter;
    
    private bool canDash = true;
    private bool isDashing;
    public float dashingPower = 24f;
    public float dashingTime = 0.2f;
    public float dashingCooldown = 1f;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] private TrailRenderer tr;

    private void Update()
    {
        
        if (isDashing)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (IsGrounded())
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;
        }
        else
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumpBufferCounter = jumpBufferTime;
        }
        else
        {
            jumpBufferCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (coyoteTimeCounter > 0f && jumpBufferCounter > 0f && !isJumping)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);

            jumpBufferCounter = 0f;

            StartCoroutine(JumpCooldown());
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);

            coyoteTimeCounter = 0f;
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && canDash)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }

        Flip();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator JumpCooldown()
    {
        isJumping = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        isJumping = false;
    }
    
    private IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        canDash = false;
        isDashing = true;
        float originalGravity = rb.gravityScale;
        rb.gravityScale = 0f;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * dashingPower, 0f);
        tr.emitting = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
        tr.emitting = false;
        rb.gravityScale = originalGravity;
        isDashing = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingCooldown);
        canDash = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: All of your post seems to reduce to: "Why does my character dash at the same speed as when walking?" In `FixedUpdate()` you seem to be using a `speed` modifier but you're not altering it in your `Dash()` coroutine, so... double speed before `WaitForSeconds(dashingTime)` then halve it after?

Comment: awesome glad to hear it :)